# Preprocessing Python function AST nodes for LSTM model to infer parameter datatypes

Tags: python, lstm, abstract-syntax-tree

I am currently working on a project involving the training an LSTM model using the AST of Python functions to infer the datatypes of function arguments. After successfully parsing the code and isolating AST nodes related to function arguments, I'm seeking guidance on the precise steps for preprocessing these AST nodes to enable the datatype inference.

I think identifying special operators or functions indicative of data types within the AST will be really useful.

Specifically, I want to know how to convert or preprocess the AST nodes to facilitate the LSTM in dynamically inferring the datatype of each function argument. Are there recommended methods or key considerations for this particular step?